# How to call a function that yields IEnumerable results?

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable, yield

Here is my server side code which is executing a SQL stored procedure and sending me some table results.

```
public IEnumerable<IDataRecord> SomeFuncToCallDB(string pName, SqlParameter[] sqlParams, int commandTimeout = -1)
    {
        using (SqlConnection cn = GetNewConnection())
        using (SqlCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = pName;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            if (commandTimeout != -1) cmd.CommandTimeout = commandTimeout;
            if (sqlParams.Length > 0) 
            { 
                FixNullParams(sqlParams); 
                cmd.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParams); 
            }
            cn.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    yield return (IDataRecord)dr;
                }
                cn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the FixNullParams Function.

```
        private void FixNullParams(SqlParameter[] parameters)
    {
        foreach (SqlParameter p in parameters) if (p.Value == null) p.Value = DBNull.Value;
    }
```

When, I call this function like this,

```
                List<SqlParameter> parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@AgencyFilter", "CountyPool"));
            IEnumerable<IDataRecord> dataFromDB = salesTax.SomeFuncToCallDB("[Data].[uspSomeSQLProc]", parameters.ToArray());
```

I get the following exception.

**"The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection."**

This happens at the line cmd.Parameters.AddRange.

At the same time, if I call the same function like this,

```
List<SqlParameter> parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@AgencyFilter", "CountyPool"));
            //IEnumerable<IDataRecord> dataFromDB = salesTax.SomeFuncToCallDB("[Data].[uspAgenciesSelect]", parameters.ToArray());
            foreach (IDataRecord eachRec in salesTax.SomeFuncToCallDB("[Data].[uspSomeSQLProc]", parameters.ToArray()))
            {
                int x = eachRec.FieldCount;

            }
```

Then it's working fine and looping through each record.

Here are my questions.

1. Which is the right way to call this procedure ?
2. How is it not failing in the later call but fails in the former ?
3. If I have to write a Unit Test for this function, I just want to get IEnumerable and then assert the record count. But it looks like, I can't do this kind of test because of this Exception. So what's the right way for unit testing this function ?

Comment: Well where do you create `parameters`? Presumably you're using parameters which are already used elsewhere. Please clarify your question, edit the code sections so they're as readable as possible (rather than indented a long way over), and ask *one* question per post.

Comment: Enumerable methods generate a state machine when compiled. I can't tell you the nitty gritty details but I think that has something to do with it. If anyone would know it is Jon Skeet.

Comment: @JonSkeet I believe you are correct, the OP is not describing the part of his code that contains the problem, only where the error is caught.  We need you to account for the location and usage of SQL parameters class instances. OP is reusing a sql parameter. Perhaps the "FixNull" method you are using provides the same "empty" parameter, or whatever it returns and this confuses the system, but honestly, we can not determine the cause of the error with the code you have provided.

Comment: I have added the missing information in the code. Just wondering how the call works one way and fails the other way. Hoping to learn something new.

Comment: The body of iterator methods are not entered until iteration by foreach so I find it hard to believe that doing only what is shown in the first snippet throws but the second one does not. The second one must execute all the same code as the first and then some. Is there is something going on after what you've shown where you are using `parameters` again?

Comment: Please attach full stack trace of exception. I doubt code you provided can produce such exception, because method `SomeFuncToCallDB` is not even executed until you start enumerating results.

Answer (score 0):

I think, I found the problem. It's the **debugging behavior** in Visual Studio 2017.

I was able to create a small test database and then a simple windows application to replicate this issue. Both calls behave the same.

But, when I perform line by line debug operation, this exception creeps in as shown in the below snapshot.

[image]

For curious users, I have added the complete source code here.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Iterator
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            List<SqlParameter> parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@hobbyName", "Coding"));
            IEnumerable<IDataRecord> dataFromDB = GetUserInfo("dbo.GetUserBasedOnHobby", parameters.ToArray());
            int totalCount = dataFromDB.Count();
            MessageBox.Show("Total count : " + totalCount.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error : " + ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            List<SqlParameter> parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@hobbyName", "Coding"));
            List<IDataRecord> allRecs = new List<IDataRecord>();
            foreach (IDataRecord eachRec in GetUserInfo("dbo.GetUserBasedOnHobby", parameters.ToArray()))
            {
                allRecs.Add(eachRec);
            }
            int totalCount = allRecs.Count();
            MessageBox.Show("Total count : " + totalCount.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error : " + ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void FixNullParams(SqlParameter[] parameters)
    {
        foreach (SqlParameter p in parameters) if (p.Value == null) p.Value = DBNull.Value;
    }

    public IEnumerable<IDataRecord> GetUserInfo(string pName, SqlParameter[] sqlParams, int commandTimeout = -1)
    {
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MACHINE2;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = pName;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            if (commandTimeout != -1) cmd.CommandTimeout = commandTimeout;
            if (sqlParams.Length > 0)
            {
                FixNullParams(sqlParams);
                cmd.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParams);
            }
            cn.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    yield return (IDataRecord)dr;
                }
                cn.Close();
            }
        }
    }


  }
}
```

This is the sample test data.

[image]

This is the SQL script for the stored procedure.

```
USE [TestDB]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[GetUserBasedOnHobby]    Script Date: 12/9/2017 3:14:43 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetUserBasedOnHobby]
@hobbyName varchar(50)
    AS
SELECT * from dbo.UserTable where dbo.UserTable.Hobby = @hobbyName;
    RETURN 0
    GO
```

Thank you all for your comments and response. It helped me to dig deeper to discover the issue.